# Strange wm_keydown behaviour with THtmlEdit

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

This is a strange one: This is the situation

The application builds an edit form at run-time from an XML document. The UI/UX design is such that there are three levels of nested TTabControls and for the final (lowest) level the TTabItem is created at run-time. This has a TVertScrollBox which itself contains a column-grid control of mine and that (at last!) contains the THtmlEditor.

The problem is that when the controls are built and the content loaded, the THtmlEdit initially ignores keydown. It will respond to mouse events, the caret can be positioned. Switching to a different top-level tab, or away from the whole application and back, then cures the issue and the editor responds to keydown messages.

I have tried putting a breakpoint in `procedure THtmlEditor.KeyDown()` ... and then tracing back up the call-chain. There doesn't seem to be anything behaving differently. I've paid particular attention to input focus, explicitly calling Editor.SetFocus even though that is apparently already called ...

I have tried putting a conditional breakpoint in `function TPlatformWin.HandleMessage: Boolean;` ... and my only observation is that when in non-working mode, the call to `DispatchMessage(Msg)` doesn't arrive at the editor, or its parent form.

I **have** tried to build a MDC for this, replicating the structure outlined above but ... that always works!

What can I try next?
Has anyone seen this behaviour (and fixed it)?

**EDIT:**

The detail I didn't mention -- didn't think about it -- is that for the error condition to show, the control focused before the THmtlEditor is a TWebBrowser. If I set focus on a TEdit after TWebBrowser and **then** to THtmlEditor it seems to work.

Grrr!

Comment: Do you perhaps have `KeyPreview` property set to `true` on your form.? That might cause the `wm_keydown` message already being handled by your form before it reaches your HTML editor. Also do you perhaps have some other control that could be accepting the keyboard input like an Edit box for instance? If you have check to see if your key presses might not be processed by that control.

Comment: @SilverWarrior This is a Firemonkey application and I don't think there's a `KeyPreview` property.

Answer (score 0):

This is only half an answer, but for future reference, this is what I've done:

**It's a bodge** :-(

I've put a TEdit on the main form and set it invisible. I've then added a handler to the MainForm `OnFocusChanged` which sets a boolean trap-flag to track if TWebBrowser has previously been focused.

For the instances of THtmlEditor I've added an `OnClick` handler which checks the trap-flag and makes the TEdit visible, calls `SetFocus` on it, re-hide the TEdit and return True so that the THtmlEditor can re-set focus to itself. The trap-flag is to avoid unnecessarily losing focus if the user is just clicking in the THtmlEditor.

The next step -- which I may never get to -- would be to trace through the focus code for TEdit. My suspicion is that it all relates `ITextInput` which TEdit supports and THtmlEditor doesn't.